# VBA procedure to import csv file into access

Tags: ms-access, vba, csv

i need procedure in VBA  to import data into access from csv excel file without some records,, as header and footer.  Example,,, i have table in csv file, which contains some
sentence  which not belong table date

---

A1   this is some sentence title.......
A2                                                         title
A3.......
A7          DATA      DATA        DATA        DATA       DATA
A8      rows     DATA     DATA        DATA        DATA       DATA 
......
....
A256    DATA      DATA        DATA      DATA
A257    this is some  sentence

---

My Acess shoud contain only rows  between A7 to A256. Does anyone knows procedure or whatever in VBA who solves my problems  ?

thanks  a lot

---

Edit

Comment: Can you clarify, please? Excel will open a CSV, but CSV means Comma Separated Value, and it is a text file. Do you have an Excel file or a text file?

Comment: I have pasted your data into your question. As you can see, it is not possible to tell where the lines are. You need to either choose to edit your post and repaste or tidy it up. The semi-colon (;) is not the standard delimiter for a csv.

Comment: It seems that this is a once-off and you are not completely familar with VBA, so I strongly recommend you try @Olivier Jacot-Descombes method first.

Comment: i am try, but it not working :(

Comment: mistake in import table, bacause that create  only 3 false columns, but my csv, have 11 separated with  semicolon..but with this Oliver procedure separated comma...aand everthing is mistake

Comment: example i have line:   blue ; 10,090 ; 56,789   delimiter semicolon after this procedure   blue10 / 09056 / 789  ...acess recognize comma as delimiter:(

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way to do it is to link the CSV-file into the Access database as a table. Then you can work on this table as if it was an ordinary access table, for instance by creating an appropriate query based on this table that returns exactly what you want.

You can link the table either manually or with VBA like this

```
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblImport", _
    FileName:="C:\MyData.csv", HasFieldNames:=true
```

---

**Update**

```
Dim db As DAO.Database

' Re-link the CSV Table
Set db = CurrentDb
On Error Resume Next:   db.TableDefs.Delete "tblImport":   On Error GoTo 0
db.TableDefs.Refresh
DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acLinkDelim, TableName:="tblImport", _
    FileName:="C:\MyData.csv", HasFieldNames:=true
db.TableDefs.Refresh

' Perform the import
db.Execute "INSERT INTO someTable SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM tblImport " _
   & "WHERE NOT F1 IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')"
db.Close:   Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: thanks, :)   but i must writing VBA code, it is my task to find way how  from excel csv file import data into access without some rows.I need some condition because required rows ..Not respond me, that i openinig imidiatly in aceess....several times a month i got csv file with approximately  2213 rows , and i must import into acess withoat some rows on begining and in the  end

Comment: This is exactly what I am telling you. Once the CSV-file is linked into access you can import the required rows with `INSERT INTO someTable SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM tblImport WHERE NOT F1 IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')` as an example.

Comment: The question is of whether your file is really a CSV file. In order to be a CSV-file it MUST contain the same number of columns in every row! If lines 1-3 and 257 contain some plain text, then this is NOT a CSV-File.

Comment: What's happening with `WHERE NOT F1 IN ('A1', 'A2', 'A3')`?

Comment: The rows having the values "A1", "A2" or "A3" in the column `F1` are skipped, i.e. excluded from the result set. Note if the CSV file has field names in the first row and you import with `HasFieldNames:=true` then these names will be used as column names, otherwise Access assigns column names like `F1`, `F2`, `F3`... automatically.

Comment: What TransferType should be used for tab delimited file?

Comment: When you perform the import manually, you can set a delimiter and other settings. Then you can store your entries as a named import specification. The `DoCmd.TransferText` command has an optional parameter for a specification name. See [Access VBA DoCmd.TransferText Method](https://access-excel.tips/access-vba-docmd-transfertext-method/)

Answer (score 7):

Your file seems quite small (297 lines) so you can read and write them quite quickly. You refer to Excel CSV, which does not exists, and you show space delimited data in your example. Furthermore, Access is limited to 255 columns, and a CSV is not, so there is no guarantee this will work

```
Sub StripHeaderAndFooter()
Dim fs As Object ''FileSystemObject
Dim tsIn As Object, tsOut As Object ''TextStream
Dim sFileIn As String, sFileOut As String
Dim aryFile As Variant

    sFileIn = "z:\docs\FileName.csv"
    sFileOut = "z:\docs\FileOut.csv"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set tsIn = fs.OpenTextFile(sFileIn, 1) ''ForReading

    sTmp = tsIn.ReadAll

    Set tsOut = fs.CreateTextFile(sFileOut, True) ''Overwrite
    aryFile = Split(sTmp, vbCrLf)

    ''Start at line 3 and end at last line -1
    For i = 3 To UBound(aryFile) - 1
        tsOut.WriteLine aryFile(i)
    Next

    tsOut.Close

    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "NewCSV", sFileOut, False
End Sub
```

**Edit re various comments**

It is possible to import a text file manually into MS Access and this will allow you to choose you own cell delimiters and text delimiters. You need to choose External data from the menu, select your file and step through the wizard.

[About importing and linking data and database objects -- Applies to: Microsoft Office Access 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-importing-and-linking-data-and-database-objects-HP005241695.aspx)

[Introduction to importing and exporting data -- Applies to: Microsoft Access 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-importing-and-exporting-data-HA101790599.aspx)

Once you get the import working using the wizards, you can save an import specification and use it for you next DoCmd.TransferText as outlined by @Olivier Jacot-Descombes. This will allow you to have non-standard delimiters such as semi colon and single-quoted text.

Comment: my file is not small have with approximately 2213 rows, lines:)

Comment: Where i this write , in acess ?  New datebases,datebases tools, Visaul Basic...insert module??  really need help, i must finish this by monday

Comment: It is MS Access VBA. If you do not know VBA, you will have problems, there is no error coding and you have not posted a sample of the text file, so I do not know if it is truly a CSV -- a comma delimited text file. Otherwise, the code is tested to run.

Comment: if you do not mind, i can send example my csv file to your mail, and i will see tath is csv file, and if you is not difficult...test code above, and tell me where i write ,, so that i can on my computer test code above  :Sub StripHeaderAndFooter()
Dim fs As Object ''FileSystemObject
Dim tsIn As Object, tsOut As Object ''TextStream
Dim sFileIn As String, sFileOut As String
Dim aryFile As Varian

Comment: No, I do not post my email on public sites, sorry. You can right-click on the file and choose Open With --> Wordpad. This is a text editor and you will see the actual contents of the file. Cut and paste the top few lines into your answer. To test the code, just paste it into an MS Access module and step through by pressing F8. If you have never used VBA before, you will need to do quite a lot of reading to get up to speed.