# How do I import CSV files in Access VBA?

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, import

My macro can import text files from a folder:

`DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, ....`

But now, I no longer need to import text files, I need to import csv files.

How can I implement the code to achieve this?

Comment: Is this MS Access?  (I think that's the only Office product that uses `DoCmd`, but I'm not sure.)  If so, please add the [ms-access] tag.

Comment: copy of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275356/vba-procedure-to-import-csv-file-into-access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA procedure to import csv file into access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275356/vba-procedure-to-import-csv-file-into-access)

Comment: It is MS Access, sorry for the confusion