# Updating an Access Table with a CSV File Automatically

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Problem Background:

I have a Powershell script that I can execute from my Microsoft Access Form that scans through file folders that contain information on different facilities, and produces a CSV that looks something like:

```
SiteCode    FacilityNumber  DocumentType    HyperlinkPath
DKFZ        10              DD1400          C:\FACILITIES DATABASE\path
DKFZ        10              FLRPLN          C:\FACILITIES DATABASE\path
SMQL        17              P1              C:\FACILITIES DATABASE\path
SMQL        17              P2              C:\FACILITIES DATABASE\path
```

So that way every time new files are added to those folders, I can just run this script and produce an updated list of everything I have:

```
C:\...\Output\scanResults.csv
```

All I need now is to take that CSV file and update (or even overwrite) a Table that I have in an Access database, which has relationships to other tables and is used by various Queries and Forms in the database. The CSV columns are already named and formatted in the same way as the Access Table.

I've looked at and tried to replicate the following threads:

[VBA procedure to import csv file into access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275356/vba-procedure-to-import-csv-file-into-access)

[Access Data Project Importing CSV File In VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413740/access-data-project-importing-csv-file-in-vba/3417067#3417067)

[VBA Import CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923256/vba-import-csv-file?rq=1)

The closest answer I found is:

```
Sub Import()
   Dim conn as new ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs as new ADODB.Recordset
   Dim f as ADODB.field

   conn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=c:\temp;"
   rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [test.txt]", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

   While Not rs.EOF
      For Each f In rs.Fields
         Debug.Print f.name & "=" & f.Value
      Next
   Wend
End Sub
```

But this obviously won't write the data into the table, and I could not understand what the author was trying to say with respect to changing Select to Insert.

I've also found:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "YourCustomSpecificationName", _
    "tblImport", "C:\SomeFolder\DataFile.csv", False
```

Since both of these are from 2010, I wonder if there isn't a better way to accomplish this in Access 2013. And while I can do this all manually, I would like to incorporate it into the VBA code I use to tell Powershell to produce the CSV, that way I can make it and then upload it immediately.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated. I'm still very green to Access, VBA, and SQL statements in general, so this has been very much a "learning as I go" process.

Comment: The author is suggesting something like: `INSERT INTO tablename([field1], [field2], [field3]) SELECT [field1], [field2], [field3] FROM [test.txt]`. However, using this statement to set a recordset object and code looping recordset makes no sense to me. Have you considered just setting a link to the CSV file? As long as you replace the file with the same name and structure every time the link should be stable. Then work with the linked table like any other table, except cannot edit data.

Comment: Ahhh, alright, that makes a lot more sense now. So that's actually the first thing I tried to do, create a linked table to my CSV that can be updated outside of Access. Unfortunately, I run into two issues; my queries take significantly longer to run while actively using the Form, and when the Form first opens I get several "The record source.... specified on this form does not exist" errors which seem to be resolved by closing the form and then reopening it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use SQL clauses and queries to import such data. The details depend on your exact configuration, but it tends to look something like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO MyTable
FROM [Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=No;DATABASE=C:\...\Output].[scanResults#csv]
```

Or append the information to the table instead:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(SiteCode,    FacilityNumber,  DocumentType,    HyperlinkPath)
SELECT *
FROM [Text;FMT=CSVDelimited;HDR=No;DATABASE=C:\...\Output].[scanResults#csv]
```

This allows you to do checks before importing (using a `WHERE` clause), import only specific values, and allows you to customize a lot without using external files.

`DATABASE=` is followed by your folder name (use `{}` if there are characters that need escaping in there), and then followed by your file name with `.` replaced with `#`.

You can execute it by either saving it as a query, or using it as a string in either VBA or a macro. Note that I rarely recommend macro's, but you *can* execute them using a scheduled task and close Access after importing.

To backup and restore a relation before and after updating, you can use the following functions:

```
Public Function DeleteRelationsGiveBackup(strTablename As String) As Collection
    Dim ReturnCollection As Collection
    Set ReturnCollection = New Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim o As Integer
    Do While i <= (CurrentDb.Relations.Count - 1)
        Select Case strTablename 
            Case Is = CurrentDb.Relations(i).Table
                ReturnCollection.Add DuplicateRelation(CurrentDb.Relations(i))
                o = o + 1
                CurrentDb.Relations.Delete CurrentDb.Relations(i).NAME
            Case Is = CurrentDb.Relations(i).ForeignTable
                ReturnCollection.Add DuplicateRelation(CurrentDb.Relations(i))
                o = o + 1
                CurrentDb.Relations.Delete CurrentDb.Relations(i).NAME
            Case Else
                i = i + 1
        End Select
    Loop
    Set DeleteRelationsGiveBackup = ReturnCollection
End Function

Public Sub RestoreRelationBackup(collRelationBackup As Collection)
    Dim relBackup As Variant
    If collRelationBackup.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    For Each relBackup In collRelationBackup
        CurrentDb.Relations.Append relBackup
    Next relBackup
End Sub

Public Function DuplicateRelation(SourceRelation As Relation) As Relation
    Set DuplicateRelation = CurrentDb.CreateRelation(SourceRelation.NAME, SourceRelation.Table, SourceRelation.ForeignTable)
    DuplicateRelation.Attributes = SourceRelation.Attributes
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fldLoop As Field
    Do While i < SourceRelation.Fields.Count
        Set fldLoop = DuplicateRelation.CreateField(SourceRelation.Fields(i).NAME)
        fldLoop.ForeignName = SourceRelation.Fields(i).ForeignName
        DuplicateRelation.Fields.Append fldLoop
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Function
```

And then, when importing:

```
Dim colRelBackup As Collection
Set colRelBackup = DeleteRelationsGiveBackup("MyTable")
'Delete MyTable
'Import new version
RestoreRelationBackup colRelBackup
```

(Note that the code is quite long, developed for a project several years ago, and not extensively tested. If a field name/type is not **exactly** like how it was before the import, the restore of the backup might fail and the relations will be permanently lost).

Comment: Thank you, I just tested it in a Query, however I get the following error: "You can't delete the table 'TblFacilityHyperlinks'; it is participating in one or more relationships", is there a way to force INTO, or should I instead run this query to collect the data from the CSV and use that to update or append the original table?

Comment: That's not very descriptive at all. Errors deleting tables can depend upon if a table is linked, if a database is shared, security setup, relationships, dependencies and more. Unless you provide more information, you will need to figure that out yourself.

Comment: I apologize, but the only additional line in the error message effectively repeats the first line:

"If you want to delete this table, first delete its relationships in the Relationships window"

It won't let me insert the data from into the original Table without deleting it first, and it won't let me delete it without deleting the relationships it's a part of.

Comment: See the current edit. You can empty the table before inserting the new info.

Comment: I just had to change HDR=Yes, and everything imported quickly and easily! Although I still need to resolve the issue of deleting the relationships when the table is replaced. I want to retain all the table relationships so that I don't have to go back through and recreate them after putting the new information in.

Comment: Ah, yes, if your CSV contains headers, that should be yes. I can share some VBA that backs up all relations for a table, then deletes the table, executes the import, and then restores them again. It's risky code though, since restoring the relation will fail if the field type or name is not exactly what it should be

Comment: I would definitely be interested in taking a look at that if it's not too much trouble. Fortunately my field types are simple, so as long as they don't put a string where a number should be it should run smoothly.

Comment: It's so far worked incredibly well, I finally had the opportunity to test it out this morning.

Comment: Although now I see the issue you were talking about, I have one column that is a different data type than the others, and it caused all the relationships to be deleted for that particular table when I executed the code.

Answer (score 2):

So some high level architect advice:  replacing data versus replacing table

It is easier replacing data - - the new incoming data must be the exact same structure as the existing table (i.e. same field names and no new fields).

- - just fire a Delete Query to the existing table that clears out all records
- - then fire an Append Query to the linked CSV file that writes all those records into the existing table

very simple really.

You can replace the tables if you must - and you are already down this path.  You can delete those table relationships entirely.  That table relationship feature is useful - but not mandatory.  You can create relationships at the query level as an alternative.  Essentially the table relationships just auto create the query level relationships.  If you delete the table relationships then one must simply create the table relationships at the query level manually - they don't automatically appear.  Note however that if one is relying on cascade deletes or referential integrity, then removing table relationships will undo that - so you should check these points.

Deleting Table Relationships will not break any existing queries.  Their table relationship join lines will remain intact.

Comment: That, is extremely helpful. I wish I'd known that from the outset actually, for the application I have query level relationships would probably work just as fine. I haven't really enforced referential integrity explicitly, since the primary and foreign key IDs are based on the actual facility code and number combination that is not duplicated anyway, or modified.