# Loading data from CSV-File to MS-Access as Read-Only

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I need to import data from a `.CSV` file into my MS Access database, but as read-only, so the `.CSV` file can be updated and changed.

The `.CSV` file is automatically generated by another system and saved in a specified path regularly (e.g. every hour). I need the data from this (periodically updated) `.CSV` file into my MS Access database and I need it to be updated as well (not in the exact moment when the `.CSV` file is updated, but every time I execute a query, I need it to use the most recent data).

I can easily import the `.CSV` file with the Linked Table Manager in MS Access, but the problem is, when I have my queries and forms opened, MS Access locks the `.CSV` file. Thus I am not able to change data in the `.CSV` file or overwrite the file with a new version.

Furthermore I plan to have multiple people to use the database in parallel.

Is there a way to import (or link) the data in the `.CSV` file into Access (linking the table, query,...) without locking it? Such that MS Access only reads the data from the file when the queries are executed?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe create a temporary copy of the file and link that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, FunThomas! 
You mean to manually copy the file? I expect to receive updated files hourly, I´d prefere to avoid manual steps. Or do you see a way to atomatically make such a copy and link it?
Plus: This data base will probably be used by multiple users, so to overwrite the temporary file, I would ned all of the users to quit access, is that correct?

Comment: Okay, was not aware about your setup. I thought you link this table only temporary (to create reports or to import some of the data) and only for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I edited the question to make it clearer!

Comment: You can certainly open the file as read only (through SQL, by querying the CSV directly without using a linked table and making sure to use a snapshot-type recordset). But that still locks the file. I don't think you can work with Access without locking the file or making a temporary copy of its contents.

Comment: When linked, Access will only lock the file while having the table open. So, close it at once when read and imported, and the source can update the file at any time.

Comment: @ErikA: I tried to figure out how to load the CSV through an SQL query, but I only found examples of doing it via VBA macro. Can you give me a hint how such a SQL query must look like? If the table is locked only temporarily (when Access reads the data to execute all queries, but not all the time the forms are opened), that would be sufficient for my application, I guess!
Thanks!

Comment: @Gustav: The problem is, the forms, tables and queries in Access will be opened most of the time, since multiple users are supposed to work with it and use it to look up informations many times a day. It will be hard to find a time of day where no one has the data base opened - especially not every hour (which is the cycle time I would like to update the CSV). If you can think of a work around, I would very much appreciate!
Thanks!

Comment: @Grabu See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49044948/7296893, first bit of the answer, for an example. But with a query the dataset is still locked while the form is open, afaik, since the recordset stays open for the lifetime of the form and keeps the CSV locked, even when opening it as a read-only snapshot. You may experiment with binding forms to disconnected ADO recordsets, that might just work.

Comment: @ErikA thank you for that hint. I tried to figure out your proposed solution with disceonnected ADO recordsets, but I cannot really figure out how that is supposed to work. Do you load the data as an ADO recordset via vba or using a query? You would then refere all queries and forms to this recordset?
Thanks!