# Barcode using Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, barcode

I am planning to use an HID barcode reader to spool data then it will be read as a data source for Microsoft Access? Is this possible? Can I do it in the background? Thanks.

Comment: How does your model of BCR communicate?  Most basic models act a keyboard, simply entering the barcode number as if it was typed in, and therefore can be used anywhere you can type a number manually.

Comment: it uses USB connector, i just need to gather all barcode scans in the background then use MS Access to manipulate it. Its for an order system where the items ordered uses barcode and hopefully collect them in a text (CSV, etc.) or database file

Comment: So it stores barcodes and then sends them together (a "batch") via USB... but in what form?  ie., does it have its' own software interface that creates a file? Send them as keystrokes?  If you're not sure, I might be able to look it up quickly if you have the BCR's brand & model number handy.

Comment: Here is the one I am planning to get "Symcode MJ2090 Auto Sense Laser Barcode Scanner". I am thinking if its possible to dump all the scans in one file (dbf or text) in the background while I link to the file using MS Access in the foreground? Thank you very much for answering my questions.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, if you have a barcode reader that creates a `.CSV` or `.TXT` file with a list of barcodes, **yes**, you should be able to import the list into Access.  (Any *valid* `.CSV` file, and most well-structured `.TXT` files.)

This [**Stack Overflow post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275468/8112776) shows how to load a CSV file using VBA.

And [**here's how**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-a-text-file-d6973101-9547-4315-a8f8-02911b549306) to do it manually.

---

Questions about the specific model are off-topic for this site **but since I was the one that asked** for that information, I did look into it quickly...

[image: img]
`Symcode MJ2090`

It looks like this product is made specifically for sale on Amazon/eBay, and every page I clicked has the identical copy/pasted description.

It raises an alarm for me that the "standard description" doesn't specify how the data is output to the computer other than `"USB, No Driver Required"`.

Also, the Chinese [manufacturer's sketchy site](http://www.symcode.com.cn/productgrouplist-802162118/1D_Barcode_Scanner.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.prup15aafb.3.cb694198cN9vkf) gave me browser security warning, and then doesn't even list this product in their list of BCR's.  Perhaps it was a failed product that they unloaded cheap to resellers.

I've bought cheap USB electronics in the past (recent example: SIM Card reader/writer) which, while one would *assume* include the software necessary to ***use*** the product, that's not always the case, and since the description didn't actually *say* it includes software, they didn't break any rules and the item is now nonreturnable due to delay, etc.

Technically, if I was so inclined (and skilled in the correct areas) I could write software to communicate with my device, but that would be the equivalent of writing a printer driver from scratch.

My point is, be 100% sure how the device send the data to the computer before purchasing, or else shell out a few extra bucks for a *known* brand name instead of a no-name product.

---

I didn't look very closely but when searched eBay for `USB barcode reader`, sorted by "lowest price + shipping", the first result was [this one](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/USB-Wired-Barcode-Scanner-1D-Bar-Code-Handheld-Scan-Reader-Store-Express-A6H6/122267891993) is $18 USD (free shipping) and specifically says:

```
Supported Interfaces: RS232 / PS2 keyboard / USB
```

...although it's wired.

---

Or [this one](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/YHD5600-High-Speed-Wireless-USB-Barcode-Scanner-Scan-Gun-Label-Reader-Store-R1V1/401490492193) is $25 USD (free shipping) is wireless and says it:

```
Supports instant upload mode and storage mode(store 200 barcodes).
```

..which sounds promising, but "supports" doesn't mean it "does it"...  however it's easy to contact the seller and find out.

---

Price aside, looking at a reputable store, [I think this $80 USD model](https://www.staples.com/Motorola-LS2208-SR20007NA-General-Purpose-Barcode-Scanner/product_IM1QX8811) would work for you, but you'll need to check the documentation from the [reputable] manufacturer (**Motorola**) into it further to confirm. (I've never bought one.)

Or, I betcha [this $10000 model](https://www.staples.com/Socket-CHS-7Ci-1D-Barcode-Scanner--Handheld--Blue/product_IM1UX1197) will work too.  :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. Can you recommend to me a reliable and a barcode scanner that can do CSV or text pooling in the background? I know Ms Access can link to a CSV file as a data file.

Comment: @DonBosi - I added specific models to the bottom of the answer but I can't give any specific recommendations since I've never bought one.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. I still want to be sure which one generates a text or log file in the background that I can tap or link into with MS Access. :(

Comment: Yes you do need to be sure.  :)  [so] is a site for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Perhaps try asking here: 
[**Stack Exchange Hardware Recommendations beta**](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)