# VBA Importing CSV to access

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access

I'm creating a code to import a list of csv's into various tables. The code loops through the csv's and tables to import each one a create a table. The code works perfectly but only when I have the csv open. Why do I have to have the csv open? And how do I fix the code so that I do not have to have each csv open?
Code is:

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim filepath(3) As String
Dim tablename(3) As String

filepath(1) = "N:\CompanyA\Model\2018-09-01\Inputs\Tomato.csv"
filepath(2) = "N:\CompanyA\Model\2018-09-01\Inputs\Apple.csv"
filepath(3) = "N:\CompanyA\Model\2018-09-01\Inputs\Pear.csv"

tablename(1) = "8594_Tomato"
tablename(2) = "15692_Apple"
tablename(3) = "10567_Pear"

For i = 1 To 3
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , tablename(i), filepath(i), True
Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Comment: When you say "have the file open", do you mean you open it in excel or something similar ? Access will have to "open" the file to read the contents, and normally will expect exclusive access to it during the import. But it should then close it again afterwards.

Comment: Yes I have to open the csv in excel for the code to work. Thanks

Comment: Try using the `TransferText` method instead of `TransferSpreadsheet`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275468/4717755) for an example.

Comment: You never actually open the file in your code. Do it like this:
http://www.homeandlearn.org/open_a_text_file_in_vba.html