# Change value of the column .csv file using Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, concatenation

I have a .dat file that I saved as a .csv and it imports in a table, OK. But this file has in the first column `= HOUR "hnnss"`. The file name contains the date that I already managed to separate it and save it in a variable=date.

My problem is: when saving the file as .csv I need to open the file, change the values of the first column from `hnnss` to `data hh:nn:ss` and then save and close, only then do I import it into the table. It needs to be in that sequence. Thanks for help.

PS: I'm using Access 365 + VBA 7.1

[image]

Comment: Which part you do not know how to do? Reading file, finding the column or changing the time format ?

Comment: Hi Vlado, thanks for your answer. I need read the value in column HOUR (red) and change to the format green dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss . This part red is just the time hh;nn:ss  , but I have an variable with the date, so I have to do Mydate & hh:nn:ss in this column.

Answer (score 0):

Andreia: You can read the file using method like in here [Import csv to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11275673/7526564) and in this loop :

```vb
    For i = 2 To UBound(aryFile) - 1  ' in your case start with second line
        tsOut.WriteLine aryFile(i)
    Next
```

implement the formatting like this:

```vb
    ' in your case start with second line if the 1st is header
    For i = 1 To UBound(aryFile) - 1  
        aryRow = Split(aryFile(i), ",")
        aryRow(0) = formatTime(aryRow(0), aryRow(?)) ' replace ? with index of date field
        tsOut.WriteLine Join(aryRow,",")
    Next
```

The above code is using function `formatTime(fieldWithTime, fieldWithDate)` which you need to write and which returns your formatted string for the whole date. I leave it for you. If you won't be able to code it let me know but in that case you rather read some books about VBA programming.

*Note: I did not debug the code. This is just an idea.*

Comment: I checked my previous scripts and saw that I was converting the .dat file to .csv and added a replace ":" and that's why I was wasting my ":" hours. So, I canceled that part and I didn't need to include ":" because the original file already has it.After that I used the query to concatenate the date I already had, with the hours.Thank you very, much!Now I'm going to fight with a selection of pens and date, to show on the Form (table) and then print that selection.My table has about 200 pens and I would like the Form to show only what the user selected. The same thing I must do for Graphics  :/