# Using VBA to read multiple CSV files and compact 1000000+ lines to 100+ lines

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im fairly new, and would like to know the 'best' way to solve this.

The csv files consist of 7 'colums' and 100000+ lines of data.

```
RowID;Date;Type;Lot;Part;Test1;Test2
```

I can outright ignore the RowID and Type columns but i want to create a row in my table for each unique set of date;lot;part. (If any of the 3 change it should start a new line, where it counts the amount of lines in the csv files where test1 and test2 are passed)

example output:

```
Date:21-2-2022
Lot:24051000
Part:100001
Test1:3407
Test2:3302

Date:21-2-2022
Lot:24051009
Part:100001
Test1:5601
Test2:4590
```

I used to do this in Excel but quickly found that this was impossible to maintain for more than a year (rowlimits etc.)

Edit:
I will need to update this table with new data every once in a while (no set timetable), as the CSV files are created automatically by a machine and this table needs to be updatable by anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Andre, readability is a lot better now. Can you explain how you did that for future?

Comment: If you want to know how people formatted code/tables/etc. click "Edit" (if available) or the "edited x-time ago". That should clear things up :)

Comment: consider creating a table with a index on the 3 columns set as unique. Then when you do a import, any existing rows will be ignored when they have the same 3 column values.

Answer (score 2):

I would link or import the file, see here: [VBA procedure to import csv file into access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275356/vba-procedure-to-import-csv-file-into-access)

Then run a query like this (adapt Test criteria to your data):

```
SELECT [Date], [Lot], [Part], COUNT(*) AS Num
FROM MyLinkedCsv
WHERE Test1='Pass' AND Test2='Pass'
GROUP BY [Date], [Lot], [Part]
```

This might be very slow with a linked CSV of 100k rows.
Then import the data instead into a temp table (`DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim`), run the query, then DELETE * from the temp table.

Once this works as desired, change the SELECT query to an INSERT query.

Comment: I see how that would work, thanks for explaining it clearly but i also realize i made an error in my question, will update it asap

Comment: That doesn't really change things, if records already exist, use an UPDATE query instead of INSERT.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, busy with other things. i'm getting the gist of it but im stuck on the fact that my csv files use ";" instead of "," as a delimiter.  how do i seperate my values into seperate fields?

Comment: Fionnuala's answer describes how to deal with non-standard CSV files. You'll need an import specification. @CmdrBadger

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileSystemObject object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361) to read the file line by line.

Parse these as you like, and - for every complete data set - append those data as a record to the destination table.

Comment: Thanks, but im still unsure how to continue. Do i use openastextstream?

Comment: No. Use [ReadLine](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/3221/reading-a-text-file-using-a-filesystemobject).